# Open terminal and run commands on Mac User Login

Tags: macos, automator, launchd, launch-agent

I am trying to automate a part of start up script that would open a terminal window that would run commands and display a bunch of text to user upon login.

I tried to create a plist in /Library/LaunchAgent that doesn't seem to do the trick

/LaunchAgents/blah.blah.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "..........">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>terminal.menu</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/bash</script>
        <string>/Library/Scripts/Startup.sh</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

and the Startup.sh looks like this

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"
    do script "echo blah blah ; ssh blah blah"
end tell'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on information from [here](http://www.launchd.info), there are a couple of edits you could make to your `.plist`:

1. The `label` value should match the name of your `.plist`, in this case `"blah.blah"`, or you should save your `.plist` as `"terminal.menu.plist"`.
2. You've specified `ProgramArguments`, but no `Program`.  Perhaps if you change this:

   ```
   <key>ProgramArguments</key>
   <array>
       <string>/bin/bash</script>
       <string>/Library/Scripts/Startup.sh</string>
   </array>
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   <key>Program</key>
   <string>/Library/Scripts/Startup.sh</string>
   ```

So your `blah.blah.plist` definition would now look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "..........">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>blah.blah</string>
        <key>Program</key>
        <string>/Library/Scripts/Startup.sh</string>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```